# Issue with calculating score

Tags: python, function, input

I am trying to generate a blackjack game but I cannot get the values my_score and computers_score to update. They keep giving me value of 0. Can anyone advise?

Code is below. I am expecting the sums of the picked cards for my hand and computer's hand to correspond to the scores, but I am getting return values of 0.

```
import random

# Create the deck and two empty hands
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
my_hand = []
my_score = 0
computers_hand = []
computers_score = 0

# Choose two cards from deck randomly and place into each hand
def hand_builder(chosen_hand, chosen_score):
    pick_card = random.choice(cards)
    chosen_score = 0
    chosen_hand.append(pick_card)
    chosen_score += pick_card

for n in range(2):
    hand_builder(my_hand,my_score)
    hand_builder(computers_hand,computers_score)

print(my_hand)
print(my_score)
print(computers_hand)
print(computers_score)
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Please [edit] to add an appropriate tag, so that experts in that language will find the question and be able to help you.

Comment: You are not getting *any* return values, because your function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return your values:

```
import random

# Create the deck and two empty hands
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
my_hand = []
my_score = 0
computers_hand = []
computers_score = 0

# Choose two cards from deck randomly and place into each hand
def hand_builder(chosen_hand, chosen_score):
    pick_card = random.choice(cards)
    chosen_score = 0
    chosen_hand.append(pick_card)
    chosen_score += pick_card
    return chosen_score

for n in range(2):
    # save the output from the function
    my_score += hand_builder(my_hand,my_score)
    computers_score += hand_builder(computers_hand,computers_score)


print(my_hand)
print(my_score)
print(computers_hand)
print(computers_score)
```

The reason that the `_hand` variable is updated is because it is a list. One can update a list in a function without returning a value.

Please read for exmaple: https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/understanding-mutable-and-immutable-in-python/

Or use google to look into mutable and immutable variables.

Comment: The function takes arguments, doesn't matter what. The function does something and it _can_  return something (if noting then it returns still something, namely `None`). You can store the function output in a variable. In this case I use `+=` to add the `chosen_score` to the `my_score` variable.

Comment: I tried your solution but the _score isn't being increased every time a hand is drawn. In the second run of the for loop, the _score is still 0, so when you run the program instead of printing the sums of the hand, it is returning the second card pick only.